# CPQLOFG XML "Syntax error"

Tags: hp, xml, ilo

HP Lights-Out Configuration Utility- CPQLOCFG v. 4.00 dated 04/04/2012

Whatever input I use, whether a sample file from the HP Web site, whether an empty file or whether a file just containing

```
<RIBCL VERSION="2.0">
</RIBCL>
```

the HP utility *always* returns

```
 CHECKING XML SYNTAX...
1 - Syntax error: Line #0: syntax error near "" in the line: ""
```

What's wrong with me or the utility? Did anyone ever get this to work?

Comment: I tried different encodings for the file too.

Comment: Been a while, I don't remember what version it was, but I have used it. Is there a reason you're stuck on that particular version? Same prob with an older or new version?

Comment: It was difficult enough to find any version on the HP Web site. I am not so much "stuck" with this version but that's simply the only one I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, the endless cycle of change for HP support tools
Go to the HP Support Center
http://itrc.hp.com/

Search for "HP Lights-Out Configuration Utility" in the 2nd field at the top of the page
Download the first link (SP7652.exe)
This is HP Lights-Out Configuration Utility- CPQLOCFG v. 3.50 dated 07/27/2012

Search the HPSC again. This time for "HP Lights-Out XML Scripting Sample for Windows"
Download the first link (windows-LOsamplescripts2.20.0-1.zip)

I used that CPQLOCFG.EXE and the Get_FW_Version.xml from the samples zip, and found they worked for me.